# Webpage does not load CSS stylesheet depending on directory name

Tags: html, css, directory, filenames

I've been scratching my head for sometime over this one now, and it hurts.

I have a regular `directory/index.php` set up, with a nice link to my stylesheet in the same directory:`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Now I have that everywhere, and it always works. Oh, but then it doesn't, not now. In none of my browsers. It simply doesn't load the `style.css`. **Unless** I change the name of the directory to anything containing a *space*. That's right, a space. `directory asdf` actually does work.

Now, I don't want to name my directory anything with a space, because I'm a bit of a, well it's just important to me. Please tell me I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Since we don't know how your directory looks like but make sure you use `ctrl+shift+r` to refresh without the cache. Can you include your directory too?

Comment: My directory has:
index.php
header.php
footer.php
style.css
img/

Level above that is a directory with more directories with similar structure that don't have this problem.

Comment: is your website online or is it locally hosted ?

Comment: Locally hosted right now